# Number of samples needed to get a given expected distance

Tags: geometry, statistics

Suppose I have a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with surface area $A$.

How many points do I need to (uniformly at random) sample so that the expected distance from each point to its nearest neighbor is $d$?

Dimensional analysis suggests the number of samples should be proportional to $\frac{A}{d^2}$. Can anything be said about the proportionality constant, if we don't know anything about the geometry of the surface?

Comment: You'll have to assume that $d$ is sufficiently smaller than the "feature size" of the surface. Otherwise, if the surface is long and skinny, like say a cylinder with radius $r \ll d$, it will behave like a one-dimensional domain instead.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This may be assumed. I suspect we'll also need to know something about the total Gaussian curvature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you pick $n$ points. Consider one of the chosen points, call it $x$. The probability that the distance to its nearest neighbour is less than $r$ is the probability that at least one other point lies within the disk of radius $r$ centered at $x$. Since the remaining $n-1$ points are drawn uniformly from the total area $A$, this probability is simply
$$P = 1 - \left(1-a(r)/A\right)^{n-1}$$
where $a(r)$ is the area of said disk. This is therefore the cumulative distribution function of the distance from $x$ to its nearest neighbour.

When $n$ is large, $P$ is approximately $1 - \exp(-na(r)/A)$. Now it's easier to consider $r$ as a function of $a$ instead, which we can do because $a$ increases monotonically with $r$. So the *area* of the smallest disk containing another point follows an exponential distribution with rate $\lambda = n/A$, because its cumulative distribution function is
$$F(a) = P = 1 - \exp(-\lambda a).$$
Then the expected value of $r$ can be expressed as
$$\bar r = \int r(a) F'(a)\,\mathrm da = \int r(a)\lambda\exp(-\lambda a)\,\mathrm da.$$

Large values of $a$, i.e. those much greater than $\lambda^{-1} = A/n$, occur with exponentially small probability and can be neglected. So if a disk of area $A/n$ is very small relative to the curvature of the surface, one may approximate $a \approx \pi r^2$, so $r(a) \approx \sqrt{a/\pi}$, and obtain
$$\bar r \approx \frac12\sqrt{\frac An}.$$

Comment: Is it valid to maintain the approximation $a(r)\approx \pi r^2$ even for the parts of the integral where $r$ is large?

Comment: That's a good question. I think what I meant was "when $F(r)$ approaches $1$ rapidly enough that large values of $r$ (relative to the curvature of the surface) can be neglected". This will depend on $n$, $A$, and the curvature of the surface, but I haven't worked out the details.

Comment: I'm thinking for instance of the unit sphere, where $a(r)$ approaches $4\pi$ as $r\to \pi$.